# triger in Mysql update almacen

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a problem with the trigger to update the storage table.

```
create table registro_producto(
id_producto int(5) not null,
id_proveedor int(5) not null,
    id_trabajador int(5) not null,
    nombre_producto varchar(20) not null,
    u_medida varchar(20) not null,
    cantidad_producto decimal(8,3) not null,
    clase_producto varchar(20) not null,
constraint PK_ID_Producto primary key(id_producto),
constraint FK_Proveedor1 foreign key (id_proveedor) references proveedor(id_proveedor),
    constraint FK_ID_Trabajador1 foreign key(id_trabajador) references trabajador(id_trabajador),
    constraint CK_Clase_Producto check (clase_Producto in ('perecible','no perecible'))
);

create table almacen(
    id_almacen int(5) not null,
        id_producto int(5) not null,
    fecha_entrada date not null,
    cantidad_total decimal(8,3) not null,
    cantidad_restante decimal(8,3),
    constraint pk_id_almacen primary key (id_almacen),
    constraint fk_id_producto foreign key (id_producto) references registro_producto(id_producto)
);
```

this is the code to create the tables and the trigger is this

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_actualizar_almacen_registro_producto
AFTER INSERT ON registro_producto
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- Actualizar cantidad total y restante del producto
    UPDATE almacen
    SET cantidad_total = cantidad_total + NEW.cantidad_producto,
        cantidad_restante = cantidad_restante + NEW.cantidad_producto
    WHERE id_producto = NEW.id_producto;
    
    -- Actualizar cantidad restante del producto en base a las entradas anteriores
    UPDATE almacen a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT id_producto, SUM(cantidad_producto) AS cantidad_total
        FROM registro_producto
        GROUP BY id_producto
    ) r ON a.id_producto = r.id_producto
    SET a.cantidad_restante = r.cantidad_total - a.cantidad_total;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

that updates the product registered in the "almacen" table by the "registrar_producto" table but the data is duplicated and/or new products are registered with the same data
[image: error]

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: The published query will not insert to almacen so your problem is elsewhere. Please add table definition for registro_producto and sample insert statements which illustrate your problem.

Comment: ok i am update the post,

Comment: @P.Salmon If you would be so kind as to offer me the corrected code please, it would be of great help.

Comment: The published code makes little sense, You have a primary key on registro_producto.id_producto but you also have a foreign key on registro_producto.id_producto in almacen which means you cannot create almacin which you need to do before you can update it in the trigger. And I don't get why an insert trigger would update to almacin when inserting to registro_producto.

Comment: You did not publish registro_producto..

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry, I made a mistake in the table, I already corrected it

Comment: @P.SalmonSo how could the code be to be able to update the products entered in the "almacen"